# AuthSub April 15 Deprecation

Tags: google-oauth, google-analytics-api, google-authentication

I understand AuthSub will be completely deprecated/unsupported April 15th.   Years ago I created a Google Analytics API App and initially supported AuthSub for authorization (not authentication).  But a couple years ago switched to oAuth for new accounts.  And I made an option for my AuthSub accounts to transition to oAuth2 for authorization AND authentication.

However, I still have accounts that have not made the migration.  I am a bit unsure if calls using their AuthSub tokens will cease to work come 04/15.  Is this deadline only for new accounts?  Or will accounts that were originally setup using AuthSub now no longer work?

Can calls to the API still be made to the API using AuthSub tokens?  Example Call:
https://www.googleapis.com/analytics/v2.4/

Will I need to have them "re-authorize" using oAuth for me to access their Google Data via the API?

Or what about this call:
https://www.google.com/accounts/AuthSubTokenInfo

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Parts of the Google Account Authentication APIs were [officially deprecated](http://googledevelopers.blogspot.com/2012/04/changes-to-deprecation-policies-and-api.html) on April 20, 2012 and [will be shut down on April 20, 2015](http://googledevelopers.blogspot.com/2015/02/reminder-clientlogin-shutdown-scheduled.html), including [AuthSub](https://developers.google.com/accounts/docs/AuthSub).

If you use any of the deprecated APIs to access Google Analytics and do not take action before April 20, 2015, **your app will not work**.

**What to do for authenticated APIs**

All of the following Google Analytics APIs require a current version of the Google Account Authentication API:

- Core Reporting API
- Multi Channel Funnel Reporting API
- RealTime Reporting API
- Management API
- Provisioning API

If your app uses any of these Google Analytics APIs, you must upgrade to OAuth2.0. Visit our developers guides for details on [how to migrate to OAuth2.0](https://developers.google.com/accounts/docs/OAuth_ref) and for more general information about [OAuth 2.0](https://developers.google.com/accounts/docs/OAuth2). Be aware that after you upgrade, current **users will be asked to reauthorize** your app before they continue using it.

**What to do for unauthenticated APIs**

The Google Analytics Metadata API does not require authentication, but is still affected by this upcoming change. If you use the Metadata API, you must take the following actions:

1. Register your application in the [Google Developer Console](https://developers.google.com/accounts/docs/AuthSub) and
2. Update your application to include an [API key](https://developers.google.com/console/help/new/#generatingdevkeys) with each request it sends to the Google Analytics Analytics Metadata API.

For more information regarding this change, please read the [2012 Google Developers blog announcement](http://googledevelopers.blogspot.com/2012/04/changes-to-deprecation-policies-and-api.html) of this change and the more recent [2015 reminder](http://googledevelopers.blogspot.com/2015/02/reminder-clientlogin-shutdown-scheduled.html).

Comment: Thanks for reply.  All makes sense.  But what about "offline access" tokens?  Will these cease to work?  I can "force" a user to upgrade to oAuth when they come back to my site.